# Manually add delegate & datasource to UICollectionView of xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I put the UICollectionView on the UIView in the xib file.
UICollectionView is installed (GUI) in the xib file, and IBOutlet is connected.

In this case, how should we write delegate and dataSource?
(Conjecture: Perhaps, I have to write it manually as a code on my own)

Also, we could not attach Cell to UICollectionView in xib.
Does that mean i do not have to put it?
Collection.swift

```
//Collection.swift

import UIKit

class Home: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var propCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let photos = ["sierra"] //Already put to AssetsFolder
    
    //Just instance. plz do not care about this.
    class func instance() -> Home {
        return UINib(nibName: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! Home
    }
    
    func initValue(){
        propCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PropCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PropCell")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell        = propCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PropCell", for: indexPath) as! PropCell
        let propImage   = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let img         = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])
        propImage.image = img
        return cell
    }
}
```

PropCell.swift

```
//PropCell.swift
//yeah, nothing. plz don't care this too.

import UIKit

class PropCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }
    
}
```

Xib of CollectionSwift
[image]

Xib of PropCell
[image]

(If you do not understand the meaning of the question, please comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class Home: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var propCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    let photos = ["sierra"] //Already put to AssetsFolder

    //Just instance. plz do not care about this.
    class func instance() -> Home {
        return UINib(nibName: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! Home
    }
    func configureView() {
        propCollectionView.delagate = self
        propCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func initValue(){
        propCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PropCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PropCell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell        = propCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PropCell", for: indexPath) as! PropCell
        let propImage   = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let img         = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])
        propImage.image = img
        return cell
    }
}
```

**USES**

```
let home = Home.instance()
home.configureView() //called configureView() with the home instance
```